# what is it called when someone talks about something they dont know about

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

What is it called when someone says something inaccurate about something they know nothing about??

Comment: Where I work we call that _a manager_. But I am not sure you can apply that to all cases. But seriously, do you have some more context? Are you talking about a genuine mistake based on ignorance, or when someone _pretends_ to know what they're talking about when it isn't true?

Comment: Ignorant... Uninformed...

Comment: Is the statement intentionally *misleading* (The person knows the response is inaccurate), or simply *wrong* (The person provides information as a guess that turns out to be incorrect).

Comment: If they truly know nothing about the subject and are just speculating incorrectly, then it's called "ignorance", or more correctly: "ignorant speculation".  However, be aware that telling someone that they're engaging in "ignorant speculation" is likely to make them angry, and they'll protest the fact that they're "ignorant".  "Ignorant" carries a slight connotation of "stupidity."  While technically they're quite different, many people don't completely understand the difference, and assume you're calling them stupid.

Answer (score 1):

We consider the speaker to be "out of their depth," and we consider the statement to be "uninformed."
We call the speech act itself "uninformed" as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Bloviating" is my favorite. It has a hint of the terms *hot air* and *blowhard* in it, both of which are also appropriate.

An *ignoramus* is a sort of proudly ignorant person -- that fits too.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is exactly the flavor of expression you're looking for, but this is often called:

"Talking Out Of His Ass".

**Edit:** If you feel the need to downvote something, why not leave a comment saying why?  That way you're actually contributing to the community and the question.

**Edit 2:** No really.  "Talking out of his ass" is a valid phrase, that is used in a number of places, and everyone in those places knows exactly what it means, and it means exactly what the asker is asking.

It is a valid answer even if you don't like it.  If you believe the answer is of low quality and feel the need to downvote, please do so.  Ranking by quality is, after all, what makes this site useful.

However, downvoting without taking a moment to comment on why you think an answer is of low quality is basically the equivalent of a grade-school kid making farting noises out the window as the school bus drives by.  Surely we can do better?

Answer (score -1):

When someone says something inaccurate about something they know nothing about :
   Incognizant remark

- Oblivious

Comment: Oblivious is more when they aren't aware of something, such as being oblivious to the feelings of another person, not really so much talking about things they don't know.